# jquery/js: dynamically change span text on input keypress

Tags: jquery, text, keypress, html

```
 <span>This Changes as You Type in Input1</span><br>

 <input type="text" id="input1"><br><br>

 <span>This Changes as You Type Type in Input2</span><br>

 <input type="text" id="input2"><br><br>
```

When user types inside input text, I want jquery to search for span tags above and change it dynamically as the user is typing. I'm just using change in this example because if I use keypress it leaves out the last keypressed..

```
 //my jquery attempt that's not working
 $('#input1').change(function() {
 $(this).closest('span').html($(this).val()    
 });
```

Wanting to know if I can code this efficiently with classes so rather than repeating this change function for every single id. For example if I can make it a class and it will change the the text on the nearest  tag above it?

```
 //Like this?
 $('.inputclass').change(function() {
 $(this).closest('span').html($(this).val()    
 });
```

Comment: you're missing a closing brace `)` for the `.html()`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is malformed javascript. You're missing the closing `)` on your `.html()`

```
 $(this).closest('span').html($(this).val()
```

to

```
 $(this).closest('span').html($(this).val());
```

Comment: well it's not really that, but thanks for pointing that out, I just quickly typed the above as an example it's my code is much larger for posting, but I just wanted to get an idea on how I would go about doing it, hoping people could suggest jquery functions etc..

Answer (score 0):

Although `.closest()` will work just fine, I'd advise you to do the following for better structure in your html.

```
<div>
    <span>This Changes as You Type in Input1</span><br>
    <input type="text" id="input1"><br><br>
</div>

<div>
    <span>This Changes as You Type in Input2</span><br>
    <input type="text" id="input2"><br><br>
</div>
```

Enlcose your `input` and it's corresponding `span` in a parent element. And obviously, use classes, as it would avoid redundancy in your code.

Once you do this, `.closest()` will work fine, but you'd be better of using `.siblings()` then.

**jQuery:**

you're missing a closing brace `)` for the `.html()`, your line needs to be like this,

```
$(this).closest('span').html($(this).val())
```